# How to initialize change of order in python dictionary

Tags: python

I find out that order of dict in python less than 3.6 is unordered. Trying to reproduce it in shell but order is not chaning. So my question when it may happen

```
#Python 3.5.2 in shell
dict1 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
print(dict1)
#{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
print(dict1)
#{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
# same order
```

Comment: Depending on the version and the interpreter options, the order might still be *consistent* given the same keys in the `dict`. You'll need to provide more details about exactly what you are doing/seeing

Comment: Start a new shell.

Comment: A dict always stays in the same order until you add new items to it. It doesn't matter how many times you print it, or iterate over it, the sequence of keys will remain the same. This is a language guarantee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `dict` is unordered in the sense that Python makes no guarantees that the order will be consistent. That doesn't mean that you won't see a consistent ordering sometimes though.

If you need a `dict` that is ordered you should check out [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).